# Cosa significa "una Seicento giù di carrozzeria"?

Tags: meaning, adverbs

Ho ascoltato la canzone *[L'italiano](https://youtube.com/watch?v=zRDVQT_MT-o)* di Toto Cutugno, presentata al festival di Sanremo nel 1983. Nel suo testo appare l'espressione "una Seicento giù di carrozzeria" che non riesco a capire molto bene. So che l'avverbio "giù" può significare "verso il basso" ed è a volte usato in senso figurato per indicare qualcosa che sta diminuendo o peggiorando. Quindi, "giù di carrozzeria" nella canzone significa che la carrozzeria della Seicento non è in buon stato di conservazione?

Comment: Oh, interesting. I (a definitely non-native learner) always thought it literally meant that it was physically "down at the shop".

Comment: @jogloran - that would be "una Seicento ***giù in*** carrozzeria".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

È l'estensione dell'espressione:

***[Essere giù](http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/G/giu.php)***:  essere in cattive condizioni fisiche o morali. (Hoepli)

Quindi:

> Una Seicento (automobile) giù (non in buone condizioni) di carrozzeria.

Espressioni analoghe:

> - ***Essere giù di corda*** : stanco, depresso
> - ***Essere giù di morale***:  demoralizzato

Comment: Una Seicento (Fiat) giù (non in buone condizioni) di carrozzeria. - https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiat_600

Answer (score -1):

I would say he means that the Seicento is in the garage and he just got it back ('di' means from) from the repair shop.

Comment: No, it doesn't mean this.

Comment: However, welcome to ItalianSE!!!

Comment: Grazie! Uno dei miei fratelli mi ha detto che secondo lui è una macchina malmessa = One of my brothers told me that it means that the car is in bad conditions.